# Greasemonkey for IE, or other extension to modify html page

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm using Internet Explorer 8.0.6001. I'm looking for an internet explorer extension to automatically change the code of a certain webpage whenever it is loaded.

The goal is to change the width of a certain text area, because it's too small. I located and tested the change to make, thanks to the built-in Developper Tools, but I'd like to automate the process.

Greasemonkey would have solved my problem, I think. There's no Greasemonkey for IE, but searching Google for an equivalent, I found IE7Pro and Trixie.

Can someone recommend one of these extensions? Another one?

Regards,
DKM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250446(v=vs.85).aspx

Use read-write ResponseInspector to modify HTTP traffic (i.e. the request that comes back to your client)
Fiddler runs as a local proxy on your client computer. Try it - it is a very nice tool.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not as user friendly, but [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) with a user-written filter can effect the sort of change you want for IE and any other programs accessing the web through it.

Comment: Hmm, that won't do, I'm behind a firewall. That's why I wanted to look at it browser-side.

Comment: Privoxy runs locally, it doesn't matter what sort of NAT/firewall/whatever you're connecting through.